# Where's +alloc defined?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ipad

This may be a silly question. I need to know where is the `+alloc` method is defined for any Objective-C class?
If it is a class method in `NSObject` how it is inherited? Because class methods cant be inherited.
Thanks.

Comment: Of course class methods can be inherited.  They are actually no different  from any other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a class method of [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc). `NSObject` itself does not inherit from anything because it's a root class.

> ### alloc
>
> Returns a new instance of the receiving class.
>
> `+ (id)alloc`
>
> **Return Value**
> A new instance of the receiver.

Comment: -1; objective-c doesn't have static methods. You must be thinking of java.

Comment: @Graham Lee, Even though we call it class methods in objective c, its quite similar to Java static methods. We just call it by the class name directly without instantiating objects.

Comment: @charith: in Objective-C, `static` has a specific meaning. That meaning is not satisfied by a class method.

Comment: @Graham, Shall I know what it is? Im new to Objective C. Also I cant imagine how class methods are inherited. Pls explain. Thanks.

Comment: @charith: You don't call methods in Objective-C, you send messages.  To send a message you must have an object to send it to.  The only difference between a class method and a normal method is that you send the message to an object that happens to represent a class.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is defined in `NSObject` (and `NSProxy`). A quick look in the documentation would have told you that.

> because class methods cant be inherited.

Wrong. Where did you read that?